# How to collect the processing time in C?

Tags: c, time

I am collecting the total elapsed time by using two inline functions (specified and implemented in my `.h` file) as follows:

```
extern double _elapsed_time_mf; 
extern double _elapsed_time_b;

//this function returns the elapsed time in order to compute the total elapsed time of an operation
static inline struct timeval get_current_time() {
    struct timeval time;
    gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
    return time;
}

//calculate the total processed time and return the elapsed total time in seconds
static inline double get_elapsed_time(struct timeval start, struct timeval end) {
    long int tmili;
    tmili = (int) (1000.0 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
            (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000.0);

    return (double) (tmili / (double) 1000.0);
}
```

Then, when I would like to know the total elapsed time of an operation I do this:

```
void my_function() {
#ifdef COLLECT_STATISTICAL_DATA
    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval end;

    start = get_current_time();
#endif

     //a processing....

#ifdef COLLECT_STATISTICAL_DATA
    end = get_current_time();

    _elapsed_time_mf = get_elapsed_time(start, end);
#endif
}
```

`_elapsed_time_mf` is defined in only one `.c` file.

However, I am getting strange results. For instance, consider that I have another function, called `function_b`, which also collects its elapsed time (which is stored in other global variable). Then, this function makes a call to `my_function` (that collects its elapsed time according to my previous code). However, the total elapsed time of `function_b` is sometimes lesser than the total elapsed time of my_function. An example of this situations is:

```
void function_b() {
#ifdef COLLECT_STATISTICAL_DATA
    struct timeval start;
    struct timeval end;

    start = get_current_time();
#endif

    //a processing....
    my_function();    
    //another processing...

#ifdef COLLECT_STATISTICAL_DATA
    end = get_current_time();

    _elapsed_time_b = get_elapsed_time(start, end);
#endif
}
```

Sometimes `_elapsed_time_b` is lesser than `_elapsed_time_mf`. Why?
I would like to collect both elapsed times in seconds according to the clock/date/timestamp (not the CPU elapsed time).

Comment: `gettimeofday` is quite bad for collecting timing information. It doesn't have a static frequency and on some systems/configurations it can go backwards. Not saying this is what happens in your case, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: @Art What would you recommend?

Comment: `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` as a minimum (there are system specific improvements that guarantee more than monotonic clock updates) or if your system doesn't have it, look around for some better time functions that at least are guaranteed to not go backwards. `gettimeofday` is pretty much the worst case since it will go backwards, jump forward, change frequency, etc.

Comment: Could you please include a answer by providing the corresponding functions that use `clock_gettime`? That is, the functions `get_elapsed_time` that returns the elapsed time in seconds and the `get_current_time`.

Comment: @Art forget about it, I did an implementation here that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Art has commented, I am using now clock_gettime. Thus, my code is now working as expected.

My functions are now written as:

```
static inline double get_elapsed_time(struct timespec start, struct timespec end) {        
    double start_in_sec = (double)start.tv_sec + (double)start.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
    double end_in_sec = (double)end.tv_sec + (double)end.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
    return end_in_sec - start_in_sec;
}

static inline struct timespec get_current_time() {
    struct timespec time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time);
    return time;
}
```

Comment: Oh, so it was related to `gettimeofday`. Cool. Glad my guess helped.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider the implementation of get_elapsed_time. From here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html

```
int timeval_subtract (struct timeval *result, struct timeval *x, struct timeval *y)
{
  /* Perform the carry for the later subtraction by updating y. */
  if (x->tv_usec < y->tv_usec) {
    int nsec = (y->tv_usec - x->tv_usec) / 1000000 + 1;
    y->tv_usec -= 1000000 * nsec;
    y->tv_sec += nsec;
  }
  if (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec > 1000000) {
    int nsec = (x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec) / 1000000;
    y->tv_usec += 1000000 * nsec;
    y->tv_sec -= nsec;
  }

  /* Compute the time remaining to wait.
     tv_usec is certainly positive. */
  result->tv_sec = x->tv_sec - y->tv_sec;
  result->tv_usec = x->tv_usec - y->tv_usec;

  /* Return 1 if result is negative. */
  return x->tv_sec < y->tv_sec;
}
```

Comment: I understood. However, I want the result as a double value and the elapsed time in seconds. In this case, how can I convert it?

Comment: `double dif = result->tv_sec; 
     double usec = result->tv_usec;
     dif += usec/1000000.;`
Something like that...